# How to get Liquid tags to render in a Markdown link?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I'm running my site using GitHub Pages and Jekyll. I want to create a keyword that will be passed into a link that is a part of each post I create. Specifically, it looks like this:

```
title: A post
imagelink: Something
---
![Description of image](https://website.com/{ post.imagelink }.png)
```

The problem is that the { post.imagelink } doesn't render. It's like the Markdown renders first, messing up the Liquid tag. As a side note, I think it's possible that Liquid tags require double braces, but even trying that also doesn't work. Am I correct in assuming that it's an issue with the ordering of the rendering? I want the link to eventually be `https://website.com/Something.png`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll need to be double braces and refer to `page` rather than `post`:

```
![Description of image](https://website.com/{{ page.imagelink }}.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ross' answer works perfectly. And in case anyone else also needs this for local images that works too by specifying the path from `assets` onwards:

```
title: A post
img: my_image.jpeg
---
![Description of image](/assets/img/{{ page.img }})
```